# spectral value of multiple matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have two matrices $A,B$ and let $\rho(\cdot)$ denote the spectral value of the argument. If $\rho(A)<1$ and $\rho(B)<1$, then can I find a matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ such that 
$$
\|A\|<1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \|B\|<1?
$$
**Thoughts:** The spectral radius of a matrix is equal to the infimum over all subordinate norms of a matrix, so for only one matrix we can always find a matrix norm. The question is really about whether we can arbitrarily closely approximate both spectral values with the same norm.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By matrix norm, I assume you mean a norm subordinate to a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This cannot be true in general because $\rho(AB)\leq ||AB||\leq ||A||.||B||<1$ for a subordinate norm, and the product $AB$ can have arbitrary large spectral radius.

For example, take 
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right), \; B=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right).$$
Their spectral radius are both $0$, but

$$AB=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right),$$
whose spectral radius is $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it work though if $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be invertible?

Comment: Well the set of invertible matrices is dense, and spectral radius is continuous, so a slight pertubation (adding $\epsilon I_2$ to each matrix) of the above should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer.